# Visual Studio Code with React how to see usage of Component or Function

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Simply see who is using a Component or Function.

Let's say I have this in the file called Menu .js:

```
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="logo-container">
                <SVG className="brand-logo" src={photoLogo}/>
            </div>
            <nav className="nav-wrapper">
                <ul className="menu-links-group">
                    <li className="menu-link"><NavLink exact activeClassName="activeLink" to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                    <li className="menu-link"><NavLink exact activeClassName="activeLink" to="/about">About Greta</NavLink></li>
                    <li className="menu-link"><NavLink exact activeClassName="activeLink" to="/portfolio">FFF</NavLink></li>
                    <li className="menu-link"><NavLink exact activeClassName="activeLink" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div className="media-container">
                <a href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} className="font-awesome-icon" ></FontAwesomeIcon></a>
                <a href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedin} className="font-awesome-icon" ></FontAwesomeIcon></a>
                <a href="#"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} className="font-awesome-icon" ></FontAwesomeIcon></a>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Menu
```

How do I quickly find all usages of this Menu? Maybe there is some VCode plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on `Menu` and select *"Find All References"*.

[image]

Comment: Actually that only work if the file is open, in your clip the App.js must be open in the editor. Try close App,js and you see

Comment: Check this [clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCRJCWbBkxQtE8hpQx-c3Q2IiE3JtmvU/view?usp=sharing)  you see this only work when the file is open. There's a glitch the wrapper.js pops up in the result list for a split second

Comment: You're right! I've updated the VS Code to version 1.47.3 and has the same bug. Looks like a problem introduced with newest release.